# Find zip files recursively in hdfs using bash?

Tags: bash, unix, hdfs

How to find .zip files in a hdfs directory recursively using bash.

What I tried :

```sh
hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/directory | grep *.zip
```

But this command does list nothing where as there are such files in multiples sub-directories (recursively) of this directory.

I get this without grep :

```
--rw-r--r-- 3 user mistapopo 6127742 2021-06-29 15:20 /path/to/directory/data/6e.m9iujse8t6.zip
--rw-r--r-- 3 user mistapopo 5940008 2021-06-29 15:20 /path/to/directory/data/cars/a5.hkjdsjue876.zip
--rw-r--r-- 3 user mistapopo 6127742 2021-06-29 15:20 /path/to/directory/data/users/cars/4.he75fdgsgds.zip
```

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/directory > /tmp/files"
grep ".zip$" /tmp/files
```

mark the answer as accepted it it solves your issue

Comment: Thanks you let me note that I forget the -R option in my question post.. I already tried it :/

Comment: can you post more info like what you are getting when you execute without pipeline and grep and with pipeline and grep , actual o/p

Comment: I get all files without grep and I do see .zip ones

Comment: a snippet of actual o/p would be useful to see if files have some strange extensions or any other issue

Comment: see the post above :)

Comment: I modified my answer , it ll solve your issue  ,use hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/directory | grep ".zip$" and mark it as accepted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234445/discussion-between-mistapopo-and-thatguy).